# How to use MongoDb's $gte and $lte for Date and Time saved as Strings on separate fields

Tags: mongodb, date, time

I have objects saved on MongoDb with the format like this

```
{
    ...
    date: (format "dd/MM/yyyy"),
    hour: (format "hh:mm")
    ...
}
```

and i need to find all which are after a certain date and/or a certain hour, something like

```
db.inventory.find(
    { 
        date: {$gte: "20/03/2019"} 
    })
```

or

```
db.inventory.find(
    {
        hour: {$gte: "15:00"}
    })
```

or

```
db.inventory.find(
    {
        date: {$gte: "20/03/2019"},
        hour: {$gte: "15:00"}
    })
```

these don't work but that's the idea of the queries

Comment: please share example data, your document so can be determine format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you date and time are strings in order to properly query you could  convert to a valid date.

You can use an aggregation with [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) and [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/index.html) like so:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: { $concat: ["$date", "T", "$time"] },
          format: "%d/%m/%YT%H:%M"  // <-- specify the format for the conversion
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      date: { $gte: ISODate("2018-03-20") }  // <-- get all after 2018
    }
  }
])
```

You can see it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3eS-8BNl-G_)

Note that `$dateFromString` is **mongo version 3.6** and up

**Update**:

If you really need to query for the hour/minutes then you can add another projection with [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: {
            $concat: ["$date", "T", "$time"]
          },
          format: "%d/%m/%YT%H:%M"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      date: 1,
      parts: { $dateToParts: { date: "$date" }}
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "parts.hour": {
        $gte: 10  // <-- get hours bigger or equal 10
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can play with the 2nd example and see it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2jiEuyAys62)

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there any way to query for the hours alone? As in "matches any day but only for hours after 12:00"